# One instance, four clients, one is slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-express, network, windows-server

We have a small office setup with one Windows Server 2012 running SQL Server 2016 Express. The database is hosting files for our accountant software. This is a multi module software that runs projecting, accounting, personnel and so on.

One of the four computers connecting to this server is experiencing slower response time on read/write to the database. Network setup is similar for them all, so  I am wondering if this could be some kind of hardware failure, but I don't really have a clue.

Any thoughts before I tear open the box and start switching out components?

Answer (score 0):

A follow up on this one. 
Fore some reason the Server Firewall was the reason for the slow speed.

I verifyed it serveral times by turning it of and

Funny though, that it only affected one of the clients.

Anywasy, all upp and running now. 
Good speed.